# Ruby make a date key hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

How to quickly make a hash contains date key

Like

```
start_date = Date.new(2017, 1, 9)
end_date  = Date.new(2017, 1, 12)
```

How to get

```
result = 
{
  "2017-01-09": "",
  "2017-01-10": "",
  "2017-01-11": "",
  "2017-01-12": "",
}
```

Comment: Don't you [want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44129173/477037) `"2017-01-09": {}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(start_date..end_date).map(&:to_s).product([""]).to_h
```

or

```
(start_date..end_date).map(&:to_s).zip([""].cycle).to_h
```

**NB** as properly noted by @Stefan in comments, in both snippets above all the hash values refer to the same `String` instance. If it’s not an option, then you have another (my fave) solution on hand:

```
Hash.new { |h, k| h[k.to_s] = ""}.tap do |h|
  h.values_at(*(start_date..end_date))
end
```

The latter solution has a bonus:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k.to_s] = ""}.tap do |h|
  h.values_at(*(start_date..end_date))
end
#⇒ {"2017-01-09"=>"", ... "2017-01-12"=>""}
```

Now let’s deal with new date:

```
hash[Date.today] << "¡Yay!" # note the plain date is passed!
hash
#⇒ {"2017-01-09"=>"", ... "2017-01-12"=>"", "2017-05-24" => "¡Yay!"}
```

Comment: Note that in the first and second example, all hash values refer to the same string instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
(start_date..end_date).each_with_object({}) { |date, hash| hash[date.to_s] = '' }
#=> {"2017-01-09"=>"", "2017-01-10"=>"", "2017-01-11"=>"", "2017-01-12"=>""}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
(start_date..end_date).map { |date| [date.to_s, ''] }.to_h
#=> {"2017-05-24"=>"", "2017-05-25"=>"", "2017-05-26"=>"", "2017-05-27"=>"", "2017-05-28"=>"", "2017-05-29"=>""}
```